# The '--ca-file' flag of etcdctl is useless?

Tags: etcd

I have set up an `etcd` server with the command below:

```
etcd -name infra0 -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://192.168.99.240:2380 -listen-peer-urls http://192.168.99.240:2380 -listen-client-urls https://192.168.99.240:2379,https://127.0.0.1:2379 -advertise-client-urls https://192.168.99.240:2379 -initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 -initial-cluster infra0=http://192.168.99.240:2380 -initial-cluster-state new -client-cert-auth -trusted-ca-file=/home/docker/ssl/ca.crt -cert-file=/home/docker/ssl/server.crt -key-file=/home/docker/ssl/server.key
```

And I can get data from it with `curl`:

```
curl --cacert /home/kubernetes/ssl/server.crt --cert /home/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt --key /home/kubernetes/ssl/ca.key -L https://192.168.99.240:2379/v2/keys/coreos.com/network/config -XGET
```

The command above return:

```
{"action":"get","node":{"key":"/coreos.com/network/config","value":"{\"Network\":\"10.0.0.0/8\"}","modifiedIndex":10,"createdIndex":10}}
```

But when I use the `etcdctl`:

```
etcdctl --peers=https://192.168.99.240:2379 --ca-file=/home/kubernetes/ssl/server.crt --cert-file=/home/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt --key-file=/home/kubernetes/ssl/ca.key ls
```

It return:

```
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
error #0: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.99.240 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

I thought it is because the failed validation of certificate, so why does the `--ca-file` flag of `etcdctl` take effect? Or is there something wrong with my command?

The etcd version I used is:

```
etcdctl --version
etcdctl version 2.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The reason for the `curl` can access `etcd` successfully but the `etcdctl` cannot is that the self signed certificates I used is not safe enough and `curl` ignores it but the `etcdctl` does not.

Below is the steps to generating safe certificates(copyed from document of [kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/authentication.md#creating-certificates) and modified).

Firstly, you should modify `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`: set the `basicConstraints` flag to `CA:TURE` and add `subjectAltName = IP:<MASTER_IP>` under `v3_ca`.

Then you can generate certificates following below steps.

```
#1. Generate a ca.key with 2048bit 
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
#2. According to the ca.key generate a ca.crt. (-days set the certificate effective time). 
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -subj "/CN=${MASTER_IP}" -days 10000 -out ca.crt
#3. Generate a server.key with 2048bit 
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
#4. According to the server.key generate a server.csr. 
openssl req -new -key server.key -subj "/CN=${MASTER_IP}" -out server.csr
#5. According to the ca.key, ca.crt and server.csr generate the server.crt.
openssl x509 -req -days 1000 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -extensions v3_req -extensions v3_ca -extfile /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
#6. View the certificate. 
openssl x509 -noout -text -in ./server.crt
```

Then run `etcd` with below command:

```
etcd -name infra0 -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://192.168.99.240:2380 -listen-peer-urls http://192.168.99.240:2380 -listen-client-urls https://192.168.99.240:2379,https://127.0.0.1:2379 -advertise-client-urls https://192.168.99.240:2379 -initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 -initial-cluster infra0=http://192.168.99.240:2380 -initial-cluster-state new -client-cert-auth -trusted-ca-file=ca.crt -cert-file=server.crt -key-file=server.key
```

Now we can access `etcd` with below command:

```
etcdctl --peers=https://192.168.99.240:2379 --ca-file=ca.crt --cert-file=ca.crt --key-file=ca.key ls
```

Notice that the `--ca-file` flag of `etcdctl` is `ca.crt`, not `server.crt`.